# Putting big picture just below navbar (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make big picture like this: [image]

So just big picture, with big letters on it. I'm a newbie so please understand me, thanks! also how do i put big letters like that?
If someone would put it in.zip for me to examine that would be even better! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

thats called the jumbotron 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron

or

```
<div class="bigpic">
  <span class="bigletters">Big Letters</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.bigpic {
postion:relative;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
display: block;
background: url('www.pictureUlr.com');
}

.bigletters {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block
  top: 40px;
  left 40px;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
}
```

this places a div under the menu with a width of 100% and a fixed height.
Then makes an image the background of said div. It also puts a span inside (or think on top) of that div because it is absolutely positioned

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't solve my problem completely.
http://prntscr.com/5l7ek6
i need it to go full stretch, how can i do that?